# Show sha1 only with git log

Tags: git, bash

I want to write a Bash script that loops over the sha1s of commits output by an invocation of `git log`. However, `git log` gives me much more output than I want:

```
commit 0375602ba2017ba8750a58e934b41153faee6fcb
Author: Mark Amery <markamery@notmyrealemail.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 1 21:35:07 2014 +0000

    Yet another commit message

    This one even has newlines.

commit 4390ee9f4428c84bdbeb2fed0a461099a6c81b39
Author: Mark Amery <markamery@notmyrealemail.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 1 21:30:19 2014 +0000

    Second commit message.

commit bff53bfbc56485c4c1007b0884bb1c0d61a1cf71
Author: Mark Amery <markamery@notmyrealemail.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 1 21:28:27 2014 +0000

    First commit message.
```

How can I get `git log` to just output sha1s so that I can loop over them conveniently?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

An alternative to `git log --format` is the [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) plumbing command. For scripting purposes it's the recommended choice as the interface can be relied on to be stable (although for simple uses like this I'd be surprised if `git log` isn't sufficiently stable).

```
for sha1 in $(git rev-list HEAD) ; do
    : # Do something with $sha1
done
```

Answer (score 112):

You can use the [`--format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log.html#_commit_formatting) argument with a [custom format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log.html#_pretty_formats) that only includes the sha1:

```
git log --format=format:%H
```

The above command yields output like the following:

```
0375602ba2017ba8750a58e934b41153faee6fcb
4390ee9f4428c84bdbeb2fed0a461099a6c81b39
bff53bfbc56485c4c1007b0884bb1c0d61a1cf71
```

You can loop over the commit hashes in Bash like this:

```
for sha1 in $(git log --format=format:%H); do
    : # Do something with $sha1
done
```

This is slightly more verbose than [using `git rev-list`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874123/1709587), but may be your only option if you want to use ordering or filtering arguments for `git log` that are not supported by `git rev-list`, like `-S`.

Comment: You could also conceivably process multiple lines of output with xargs instead of a for loop.

Comment: Why `--format=format:%H` and not just `--format=%H` ??

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see only the latest one

```
git rev-list HEAD | head -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```bash
git rev-list HEAD -N
```

to get SHA of last **N** commits.

e.g.,

```bash
$ git rev-list HEAD -1
d9f89f4d16663d5012e5c09495f3b30ece3d2362
```