# Undelete specific empty commits after rewriting history with prune-empty

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, pruning

I rewrote git history with filter-branch & --prune-empty. Now I need to recover some commits with specific message. Can I do that? I don't run git reflog or git gc

Comment: I think if you can find out the SHA-1 hashes of the commits you nuked, you can bring them back into your branch, in a number of ways.  Those commits are probably still in the reflog.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yep, I know that they still in the reflog. But I don't know a) how to proceed throught all commits, including deleted (is filter-branch will proceed them too?) and how to restore them based on condition with specific message.

Comment: I can also get needed hashes from repo backup and restore them manually, but if it is possible, I want to avoid that and find this commits automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to [search a commit by commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124949/6309).

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29524695/6309), [`git log` has a `--grep-reflog` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---grep-reflogltpatterngt) which allows you to grep commit messages of lost commits.

You can then [list the SHA1 onl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873650/6309)y with `--format=format:%H`.